# Invalid Use of non-static member function (line 17)

Tags: vector

Here I'm sorting the vector of pairs according to second element of pair .
But it is showing Invalid use of non-static member function!!!

```
class Solution
{
    public:
    //Function to find the maximum number of activities that can
    //be performed by a single person.

    bool sortbysec(const pair<int ,int> &a, const pair<int,int> &b){
        return (a.second < b.second);
    }
    int activitySelection(vector<int> start, vector<int> end, int n)
    {
        int ans = 1;
        vector< pair<int,int> > v;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            v.push_back(make_pair(start[i],end[i]));
        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end(),sortbysec);
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if(v[i].first >= v[i-1].second)
                ans++;
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```